# How can I do to show a link in a template only for an amdinistrator?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template called *index.html*. Also I have a link in the *index.html* called *admin*. I need to show the link *admin* only for an administrator, in other words only for me.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
   <a href="mylink">my text</a>
{% endif %}
```